# Docker image does not get updated after changing Route and rebuilding the ASP.NET Core Api controller

Tags: image, docker

Normally when I update the api controller code. I rebuild the project using the batch file..

==========================================================================
rd bin /s /q

rd obj /s /q

dotnet build -c Release -o bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/publish  -r linux-x64

dotnet publish -c Release -o bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/publish  -r linux-x64 --self-contained false

docker build -t efcoreservice.azurecr.io/efcoreservice .

=============================================================================
When I run the container, it is not reflecting the code changes I made. I encountered this issue several times. I have added the rd command to make sure I clean up the output folder. It does not help.

The temporary workaround is to force delete all the images in local machine and rebuild again.
What should I do to update a docker image - when the underlying project is changed.

I  use docker-compose up and down commands to bring up the images.

Answer (score 4):

The `up` command never rebuilds if the images already exist. Use `docker-compose build` to force them to rebuild.

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1487